# Почему возникает разность в выполнении программы?

Tags: c, архитектура, процессор

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
//Size of data
long Size;
char c1;
char c2;
long int i;
long int n;

int main(void)
{
  Size = 1000000;
  c1 = 5;
  c2 = 3;
  unsigned char a[Size];
  unsigned char b[Size];
  clock_t c0, c1; /* clock_t is defined on <time.h> and <sys/types.h> as int */
  for (i=0; i<=Size; i++)
    {
      a[i]=2;
      b[i]=5;
    }
  c0 = clock();
  for (n=0; n<600; n++)
  {
  for (i=0; i<=Size-2; i=i+2)
    {
    a [i] = b[i] + c1;
    a [i+1] = b[i+1] * c2;
    }
  }
  c1 = clock();
  printf ("CPU time:        %f\n", (float) (c1 - c0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  for (i=0; i<=Size; i++)
    {
    a[i]=2;
    b[i]=5;
    }
  c0 = clock();
  for (n=0; n<600; n++)
    {
  for (i=0; i<=Size-8; i=i+8)
    {
    a [i] = b[i] + c1;
    a [i+1] = b[i+1] * c2;
    a [i+2] = b[i+2] + c1;
    a [i+3] = b[i+3] * c2;
    a [i+4] = b[i+4] + c1;
    a [i+5] = b[i+5] * c2;
    a [i+6] = b[i+6] + c1;
    a [i+7] = b[i+7] * c2;
    } 
  }
  c1 = clock();
  printf ("4x CPU time:        %f\n", (float) (c1 - c0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  
for (i=0; i<=Size; i++)
  {
  a[i]=2;
  b[i]=5;
  }
  c0 = clock();
  for (n=0; n<600; n++)
    {
  for (i=0; i<=Size-20; i=i+20)
    {
    a [i] = b[i] + c1;
    a [i+1] = b[i+1] * c2;
    a [i+2] = b[i+2] + c1;
    a [i+3] = b[i+3] * c2;
    a [i+4] = b[i+4] + c1;
    a [i+5] = b[i+5] * c2;
    a [i+6] = b[i+6] + c1;
    a [i+7] = b[i+7] * c2;
    a [i+8] = b[i+8] + c1;
    a [i+9] = b[i+9] * c2;
    a [i+10] = b[i+10] + c1;
    a [i+11] = b[i+11] * c2;
    a [i+12] = b[i+12] + c1;
    a [i+13] = b[i+13] * c2;
    a [i+14] = b[i+14] + c1;
    a [i+15] = b[i+15] * c2;
    a [i+16] = b[i+16] + c1;
    a [i+17] = b[i+17] * c2;
    a [i+18] = b[i+18] + c1;
    a [i+19] = b[i+19] * c2;
    } 
  }
  c1 = clock();
  printf ("10x CPU time:        %f\n", (float) (c1 - c0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);       

  return 0;
}
```

1. Имеется код, как я понял, программа обрабатывает массив состоящий из 1 000 000 элементов 600 раз. Сначала 1 элемент обрабатывается в цикле, затем 4, затем 10.
   Я запустил программу в виртуальной машине и получил такие результаты, почему возникла разница?

CPU time: 2.506459

4x CPU time: 2.087346

10x CPU time: 1.991994

2. Как конфликты конвейеров влияют на время доступа к памяти? (именно памяти, а не на время выполнения программы!)

Comment: Меньше сравнений, меньше ошибок бренч предиктора. Вы оптимизацию включали?

Comment: Извините, а можно по подробнее? имеется в виду, что меньше раз цикл проверяется на завершение?

Comment: Да, ну и в принципе, в первом цикле у вас N/2 сравнений и N/2 инкрементов. В последнем N/20+N/20  Нужно оптимизацию включить и ещё раз проверить. Мне кажется, такого не должно быть с -O3 =) **Upd**, сорян, не заметил, что это не плюсы)

Comment: Так это ведь связано? большее значение инкремента => меньшее количество циклов => меньше времени тратится на выполнение.
* А по поводу 2 вопроса можете что-то сказать?
Также имеется вопрос, как конфликты конвейера влияют на время доступа к памяти?
(именно памяти, а не на время выполнения программы!)
На скорость выполнения программы естественно плохо повлияет, она будет выполняться медленнее, а разве конфликты должны замедлить время доступа?

Comment: Мне кажется доступ к памяти (DDR) вас в этом примере вообще не должен беспокоить. Не знаю какой у вас комп, но скорее всего 2 Мбайта, которые занимают `a[]` и `b[]` поместятся в L2 кэше. Обмен  данными между cpu и кэшем почти наверняка идет по 128 (или 256) битным линиям (а один элемент a и b у вас 8 бит), поэтому не вижу, чтобы конвейр тут ждал данных

Comment: Это отдельный вопрос, технически конфликты конвейера могут повлиять на время доступа к памяти?

Comment: @Shadow_fiend, под временем доступа вы подразумеваете время от выдачи запроса на чтение данных от CPU в cache до заполнения регистра? И вас интересует, влияет ли на этот интервал состояние конвейера?

Comment: Сам не совсем понял, что хочет преподаватель, но думаю да, вы верно описали.

Comment: @Shadow_fiend, вы уточните у преподавателя, он вам рассказывает о неком абстрактном процессоре или о конкретном чипе? Тут может быть много вариантов.

Comment: Судя по тому, что мы рассматриваем не существующие архитектуры, скорее всего и процессор абстрактный.

Comment: @avp, Ладно, по поводу конвейера уточню, а по поводу кода, получается с каждым разом увеличивается значение инкремента, значит становится меньше циклов, следовательно программа работает быстрее?

Comment: @Shadow_fiend, да. На одно вычисление заголовка цикла (сравнение и инкремент) выполняется больше вычислений с элементами массивов. Это называется разворачивание цикла. Кстати, если оттранслируете с -O3, то компилятор должен сам оптимально развернуть их (возможно результат вас удивит)